# How to format CSV file using awk commands (Trying to avoid manual work around in the csv file) with out doing delimiter in the CSV file

Tags: bash, shell, csv, awk

I am very new to AWK ,Thanks for your suggestions in advance.

I have the question here, I am getting the output as shown below in a single row instead of multiple rows

```
hostname port
http://example.com/token                                                       80
https://digits.com                                                                  443
https://examples.demo.com?grant_type            443
http://demo/paying/security/tokens/demoitexample.com                                   80
http://demo/paying/security/tokens/demoitexample1.com                                  80
http://demo/paying/security/tokens/demoitexample2.com                                  80
http://demo/paying/security/tokens/demoitexample2.com                                  80
```

But i would like to get the output as below without doing any manual changes in csv file

**expected output as shown below**

```
hostname,port
http://example.com/token,80
https://digits.com,443
https://examples.demo.com?grant_type,443
http://demo/paying/security/tokens/demoitexample.com,80
http://demo/paying/security/tokens/demoitexample1.com,80
http://demo/paying/security/tokens/demoitexample2.com,80
http://demo/paying/security/tokens/demoitexample2.com,80
```

Here is the code where i am getting the output and that would be great if we can combine both commands in the single command.

```
grep -P '((?<=[^0-9.]|^)[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(\.([0-9]{0,3})){3}(?=[^0-9.]|$)|(http|ftp|https|ftps|sftp)://([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/+#-])?|\.port|\.host|contact-points|\.uri|\.endpoint)' abc.properties| grep '^[^#]'| awk '{split($0,a,"#"); print a[1]}' | awk '{split($0,a,"="); print a[1],a[2]}'|sed 's/^\|#/,/g'|awk '/http:\/\//  {print $2,80}
       /https:\/\// {print $2,443}
       /Points/     {print $2,"9042"}
       /host/       {h=$2}
       /port/       {print h,$2; h=""}'|awk -F'[, ]' '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++){print $i,$NF}}'| column -t
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=","} {$1=$1} 1' Input_file
```

OR if you have only 2 fields to deal with then try as per @Rafaf comment:

```
awk '{print $1","$2}' Input_file
OR
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=","} {print $1,$2}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution of RavinderSingh13 have a pitfall: If the URL contains a comma, the output CSV is broken. URLs can't contain a space (or BLANK) by defintion, so a spaces is a save field separator here.

Examples for critical input records:

```
http://demo/paying/security/tokens/demoitexample1.com?a=b,c  80
http://demo/paying/security/tokens,more/demoitexample2.com   80
```

A solution is this awk command:

```
awk '{ gsub(/"/,"\\\""); printf("\"%s\",\"%s\"\n",$1,$2)}' Input_file
```

Here the URL and PORT is quoted. The quoting of the port is not necessary if you can guarantee that it is an easy word. Additionally, all `"` chars (invalid in URL, but rarely seen) are replaced by `\"`. So a `"` in URL does not break the output. I never seen a backslash in URL, so I didn't replaced it by `gsub()`. Anyway, this does it: `gsub(/["\\\\]/,"\\\\&");` (the 4x backslash `\\\\` is reduced to `\\` by bash).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have tired your script as well, Your command will give the output with comma separated in CSV file and later we need to do wrok round in the CSV file.

Comment: Commas are allowed and usual for some sites. They are used e.g. if a parameter allows a list of numbers: `https://DOMAIN/jobs/?j=copy,clean`. And some sites support nice URL without query part: `https://DOMAIN/jobs/copy,clean`.